# undefined value when checkbox is unchecked php

Tags: php

I have this registration code.  I want people to decide if they want to be added to an email listserv or not.  The code executes appropriately when the box is checked but I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: maillist in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\register.php on line 21

when the box is unchecked.  Below is the code.  I'm not great at programming so please pretend like I'm stupid when responding.  Thanks.

```
    <tr><td>Add me to your listserve:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="maillist">  </td></tr>

    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $dob=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
    $loginid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loginid']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $emailaddress=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailaddress']);
    $description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $maillist=$_POST['maillist'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO demographics    values('$name','$dob','$loginid','$password','$description')") or DIE(mysql_error());

    if($maillist==true){
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO maillist values('$name','$emailaddress')") or DIE(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: If the checkbox is unchecked the no value will be sent through the form so you can do something like: `$maillist = isset($_POST['maillist']);`

Comment: Please [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Undefined+index) before asking a question. This problem has been answered several thousand times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML forms don't create a POST variable for unchecked checkboxes. You need to check if the variable exists to know if it's checked or not:

```
$maillist = isset($_POST['maillist']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is unchecked the `maillist` will be not set. Check `$_POST['maillist']` before using it whether is comes in post array.

```
$maillist=isset($_POST['maillist']) ? $_POST['maillist'] : '';
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the help.  Also, I tried to search for the answer but couldn't find it.  I'll try harder next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the variable is set:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="maillist" value= true>

if(isset($_REQUEST['maillist']) {
....
}
```